# dynamic data models for json request from same Api

Tags: c#, json

i am getting 2 different data model for same api how to deserialize json response in c#

1st record responce

{
        "GetPartyPartyRelationshipRs":
        {
            "Status":
            {
                "StatusCode": "0",
                "Severity": "INFO",
                "StatusDesc": "Success"
            },
            "RqUID": "1",
            "PagingOut":
            {
                "PageNumber": "1",
                "PageSize": "25",
                "SentRec": "1",
                "MatchedRec": "1"
            },
            "ResponseContext":
            {
                "Language": "?",
                "ServerDt": "2016-01-28T01:42:12.663-05:00"
            },
            "Relationships":
            {
                "PrimaryPartyId":
                {
                    "XrefCIFSystem": "SOA4FSI",
                    "CustPermId": "1022",
                    "XrefOrganizationName": "Big Bank"
                },
                "PrimaryPartyRelRole":
                {
                    "PartyRelationshipRole": "Spouse Of"
                },
                "RelatedPartyId":
                [
                    {
                        "XrefCIFSystem": "Credit Card",
                        "CustPermId": "MC540022",
                        "XrefOrganizationName": "Big Bank"
                    },
                    {
                        "XrefCIFSystem": "Deposit System",
                        "CustPermId": "987655",
                        "XrefOrganizationName": "Big Bank"
                    },
                    {
                        "XrefCIFSystem": "Investment System",
                        "CustPermId": "INV12345",
                        "XrefOrganizationName": "Big Bank"
                    },
                    {
                        "XrefCIFSystem": "SOA4FSI",
                        "CustPermId": "1013",
                        "XrefOrganizationName": "Big Bank"
                    }
                ],
                "RelatedPartyRelRole":
                {
                    "PartyRelationshipRole": "Spouse Of"
                },
                "RelationshipEffDt": "2011-10-21"
            }
        }
    }

2nd record response

{
"GetPartyPartyRelationshipRs":
{
"Status":
{
"StatusCode": "0",
"Severity": "INFO",
"StatusDesc": "Success"
},
"RqUID": "1",
"PagingOut":
{
"PageNumber": "1",
"PageSize": "25",
"SentRec": "2",
"MatchedRec": "2"
},
"ResponseContext":
{
"Language": "?",
"ServerDt": "2016-01-28T01:42:48.403-05:00"
},
"Relationships":
[
{
"PrimaryPartyId":
{
"XrefCIFSystem": "SOA4FSI",
"CustPermId": "1022",
"XrefOrganizationName": "Big Bank"
},
"PrimaryPartyRelRole":
{
"PartyRelationshipRole": "Spouse Of"
},
"RelatedPartyId":
[
{
"XrefCIFSystem": "Credit Card",
"CustPermId": "MC540022",
"XrefOrganizationName": "Big Bank"
},
{
"XrefCIFSystem": "Deposit System",
"CustPermId": "987655",
"XrefOrganizationName": "Big Bank"
},
{
"XrefCIFSystem": "Investment System",
"CustPermId": "INV12345",
"XrefOrganizationName": "Big Bank"
},
{
"XrefCIFSystem": "SOA4FSI",
"CustPermId": "1013",
"XrefOrganizationName": "Big Bank"
}
],
"RelatedPartyRelRole":
{
"PartyRelationshipRole": "Spouse Of"
},
"RelationshipEffDt": "2011-10-21"
},
{
"PrimaryPartyId":
{
"XrefCIFSystem": "SOA4FSI",
"CustPermId": "1273",
"XrefOrganizationName": "Big Bank"
},
"PrimaryPartyRelRole":
{
"PartyRelationshipRole": "Employer"
},
"RelatedPartyId":
[
{
"XrefCIFSystem": "Credit Card",
"CustPermId": "MC540022",
"XrefOrganizationName": "Big Bank"
},
{
"XrefCIFSystem": "Deposit System",
"CustPermId": "987655",
"XrefOrganizationName": "Big Bank"
},
{
"XrefCIFSystem": "Investment System",
"CustPermId": "INV12345",
"XrefOrganizationName": "Big Bank"
},
{
"XrefCIFSystem": "SOA4FSI",
"CustPermId": "1013",
"XrefOrganizationName": "Big Bank"
}
],
"RelatedPartyRelRole":
{
"PartyRelationshipRole": "Employee"
},
"RelationshipEffDt": "2011-12-08"
}]}}

in 2nd record "Relationships" is coming as List.

Answer (score 0):

This is just options , you can use http://www.newtonsoft.com/json to serialize and deserialize json (but you must create 2 difrent models ), or you can use (Not recomended in my opinion) dynamic data.

tip: if you using .NET Framework 3.5+ you can use 'Paste JSON as Classes'
copy class in json and go EDIT- > Paste Special ->Paste JSON as Classes

hope this help